# Why is the null set not a vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces

why the null set is not a vector space?

I think, because $0\times\phi\neq 0$

Comment: Where did you get the zero? That's really the point. A vector space must have a zero and the empty set does not have one.

Comment: Beware with the wording *null set* which is used for other things, the standard for $\varnothing$ is *empty set*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The axioms of a vector space $V$ explicitly require the existence of a vector $z \in V$ which, for all $v \in V$, $z+v = v$.

The empty set contains no elements, and in particular cannot contain such a vector, and hence is not a vector space.

Answer (score 5):

The set $V=\varnothing$ doesn't satisfy the axiom "There exists an element $\mathbf 0\in V$ such that $\mathbf v + \mathbf 0 = \mathbf v$ for all $\mathbf v \in V$."